# React js autocomplete user object in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete, reactjs

I want users to send messages to multiple users in the way that looks like what's implemented in angular's  [Contact Chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.chips) whilst in **rails4 + reactjs** combo.

I've tried using [this](https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput/blob/master/example/completion.html), but struggled to do the ajax load user part.

```js
@UserAutocomplete = React.createClass(
  mixins: [ React.addons.LinkedStateMixin ]

  getInitialState: ->
    tags: []
    completions: []

  complete: (value) ->
    value = value.toLowerCase()
    return @setState(completions: [])  if value is ""
    @setState completions: presidents.filter((comp) ->
      norm = comp.toLowerCase()
      norm.substr(0, value.length) is value and @state.tags.indexOf(comp) is -1
    .bind(this))

  transform: (tag) ->
    return tag  if @state.completions.indexOf(tag) > -1
    @state.completions[0]  if @state.completions.length is 1

  validate: (tag) ->
    @state.completions.indexOf(tag) > -1

  change: (tags) ->
    @setState
      tags: tags
      completions: []


  render: ->
    completionNodes = @state.completions.map((comp) ->
      add = (e) ->
        @refs.tags.addTag comp
      .bind(this)
      React.createElement "span", {}, React.createElement("a",
        className: "president"
        onClick: add
      , comp), " "
    .bind(this))
    tagsInputProps =
      ref: "tags"
      value: @state.tags
      onChange: @change
      onChangeInput: @complete
      transform: @transform
      validate: @validate
      addOnBlur: false
      placeholder: "President"

    React.createElement "div", null, React.createElement(TagsInput, tagsInputProps), React.createElement("div",
      style:
        marginTop: "10px"
    , completionNodes)
)
```

Questions:

1. How to ajax load user by tags? I use gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'
2. How should I handle the ajax loaded user data? Just use the userId or the user object to make the relationships?

Thanks.